# Aggregate per two columns while outputting all maximums of a third column

Tags: r, max, conditional-statements, aggregate

I have the following data:

```
> test2
    video_id    created count
1      10022 2012-07-04     1
2      40001 2012-07-04     1
3      70001 2012-07-04    14
4      70029 2012-07-04    14
5     100001 2012-07-04     1
6     100008 2012-07-04     3
7     100022 2012-07-15     1
8     440003 2012-07-15     2
9     470010 2012-07-15     1
```

## How I came up with this data:

This was aggregated from a previous data set, to output the number of views `$count` per date `$created` for each video `$video_id`, using the following code. At first, the values in the `$created` column were generated using `as.Date()`, but `aggregate()` would output them as `NULL`, so I converted them all to characters with `as.character()`.

```
test$created <- as.character(test$created)
test["count"] <- 1
test2 <- aggregate(test[c("count")], by=list(video_id=test$video_id,
                   created=test$created), FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

## Now what?

What I would like to do now is to output the video `$video_id` with the maximum views `$count` for each date `$created`. It is not obvious to me how I can obtain this using the `aggregate()` function, especially if there are more than two videos with the same value for `$count`, in which case I would like to output all of them (ultimately, I would like to pick one of those "top viewed videos" at random, which makes it unsatisfactory to just settle with the first `max()` that comes up).

Would it be better to separate the data into as many data frames for each date so that it will be easier to perform the analysis on each date separately?

Answer (score 2):

To do the aggregation try the package data.table

```
library(data.table)
test<-data.table(test)
test[,.SD[which.max(count)],by=created]
```

To get a random one I would just shuffle the data first:

```
test<-test[sample(1:nrow(test)),]
```

Comment: Thanks I'm just about to test it! I believe `,]` is missing from the end of your code, but I can't edit your post unless I change more than 6 characters.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `aggregate` can indeed be tricky. In your case though, you can use the `by` function,which will effectively split of your data.frame into several chunks and returns a list. For example, on your dataset:

```
> ttt = read.table(text='
+     video_id    created count
+ 1      10022 2012-07-04     1
+ 2      40001 2012-07-04     1
+ 3      70001 2012-07-04    14
+ 4      70029 2012-07-04    14
+ 5     100001 2012-07-04     1
+ 6     100008 2012-07-04     3
+ 7     100022 2012-07-15     1
+ 8     440003 2012-07-15     2
+ 9     470010 2012-07-15     1',header=T)
> by(ttt,list(ttt$created),function(x) x$video_id[x$count==max(x$count)] )
: 2012-07-04
[1] 70001 70029
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
: 2012-07-15
[1] 440003
```

This gives you a list of most-watched video for each date, which is the final result you wanted. You can further use `unlist` if you want the result as a vector, and finally `sample` to get only one `video_id` from this pool.

Answer (score 0):

another solution with dplyr (which is more easy to read IMO):

```
library(dplyr)
test %.% group_by(created) %.% filter(count %in% max(count))
```

of course you could use `sample` afterwards